# Lazarus TAChart add TChartToolSet and TZoomDragTool at runtime

Tags: runtime, lazarus, teechart

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add TZoomDragTool to a TChart. I know that TChart has built in support for zooming, but I want to disable panning (drag with right click) at the same time. There is a property to disable zooming, but no straight forward way to disable panning.

What I found out is that if I add a TChartToolSet to the chart, it will disable both the built in zooming and panning capabilities. If I can add a TZoomDragTool  to the TChartToolSet, then it will do what I want. It works well if I do it at design time, but I don't know how to do it at run time.

Appreciate it if someone could show me how to do it.

I have a small code snippet and it gives me errors if I run it.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  m_chart: TChart;
  m_toolset: TChartToolset;
  m_zoom: TZoomDragTool;  
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  m_chart:= TChart.Create(self);  
  with m_chart do begin
    autosize:= False;
    left:= 10;
    top:= 40;
    width:= 300;
    height:= 150;
    parent:= Self;
    visible:= True;
  end;

  m_toolset:= TChartToolset.Create(m_chart); //is the owner correct?
  m_zoom:= TZoomDragTool.Create(m_toolset);  //is the owner correct?

  m_toolset.Tools.Add(@m_zoom); //is this correct? 

  m_chart.Toolset:= m_toolset; //is this the way?
                               //or something like 
                               //m_chart.Toolset.InsertComponent(m_toolset);
                               //both of them crash 
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TAChart has a bit strange way of adding a `TChartTool` (which is a `TIndexedComponent`) to the `TChartToolset`. The `TChartToolset` has a `TIndexedComponentList`, `Tools`, which acts similar to a collection, and all the code of the people having difficulties here is just adding the `TIndexedComponent` to the `TIndexedComponentList` by calling its `Add` method. However, this does not do all the work. Instead, the `TChartTool` has a public property `Toolset` which you must assign to the `TChartToolset` component that you added to the form.

This is the correct code:

```
  m_toolset:= TChartToolset.Create(self); 
    // since ChartTools can be used by several charts it is safer to have the ChartToolset be owned by the form
  m_zoom:= TZoomDragTool.Create(m_toolset); 
  m_zoom.ToolSet := m_toolset;
```

Besides the ChartTools, the same code is required also for run-time created ChartTransformations.

Comment: You meant to say m_zoom.toolset:= m_toolset; right? It worked. Thank you. Please correct the post. I'll select it as the answer.